# How to show Alert View after successful data insertion in mysql?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, alert, uialertview

I want to show Alert View after successful data insertion in MySQL. How to do this?
for example. I added data to MySQL. Assume that the name and surname.I would want that after the addition of data to database automatic displaying pop ups (alert) in my program. Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use select statement with column name after insert query and use them in your popup jquery script :-)

Comment: @Jordan can you show an example? because I do not know jquery

Comment: use google .......u will get a lot example